# Replace meta tag instead selector in array for parse in php?

Tags: php

i'm newbies in the PHP development and i would like to parse the contents of a meta tags but i don't know how to proceed.

I've this code that allows me to parse the contents of these elements `#squad`, `ul[style='height:400px;']` selector.

```
// Pull in PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser
include("simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php");

// Settings on top
$sitesToCheck = array(
                    // id is the page ID for selector
                    array("url" => "http://www.arsenal.com/first-team/players", "selector" => "#squad"),
                    array("url" => "http://www.liverpoolfc.tv/news", "selector" => "ul[style='height:400px;']")
                );
$savePath = "cachedPages/";
$emailContent = "";

// For every page to check...
foreach($sitesToCheck as $site) {
    $url = $site["url"];

    // Calculate the cachedPage name, set oldContent = "";
    $fileName = md5($url);
    $oldContent = "";

    // Get the URL's current page content
    $html = file_get_html($url);

    // Find content by querying with a selector, just like a selector engine!
    foreach($html->find($site["selector"]) as $element) {
        $currentContent = $element->plaintext;;
    }

    // If a cached file exists
    if(file_exists($savePath.$fileName)) {
        // Retrieve the old content
        $oldContent = file_get_contents($savePath.$fileName);
    }

    // If different, notify!
    if($oldContent && $currentContent != $oldContent) {


        // Build simple email content
        $emailContent = "Hey, the following page has changed!\n\n".$url."\n\n";
    }

    // Save new content
    file_put_contents($savePath.$fileName,$currentContent);
}

// Send the email if there's content!
if($emailContent) {
    // Sendmail!
    mail("me@myself.name","Sites Have Changed!",$emailContent,"From: alerts@myself.name","\r\n");
    // Debug
    echo $emailContent;
}
```

The HTML DOM Parser is available here :

http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/

But, my problem is i want to change this code to get the number of comments and the rates contents in the meta tag. And, don't forget, i'm **FULLY newbies** !!!

Here is the meta tag where i would just extract the number of comments :

```
<meta item="desc" content="Comments:645">
<meta item="rates" content="Rates:112">
```

For several days I was tearing his hair to do that and I do not succeed!
Help me please!

**Very important precision, meta tags that i want to extract is not in the header of the document, but in the body!**

I'm pretty explanatory? If you need more information, ask me (in the limits of my small skills of newbie ;-))

Comment: No help for this !? Why, wrong explanatory ?

Comment: Oh, this meta is not in the header of html doc, is in body !!! i think it's important